# using Microsoft.Office.Interop Conditional coloring of the rows and column range in a excel sheet in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dataTable and want to insert the data into excel file using  Microsoft.Office.Interop. I'm iterating the dataTable and checking each row and particular column and based on the particular column value I want to colour the row. I'm facing issues with section where I have commented. Now below code if I use then it is taking the last colour and overriding the other colors. Could you please help me

Suppose I have condition as "Failed" and "Running" "Interrupted" and "Succeeded" which needs to be compared with the particular column in the dataTable and based on it I need to colour the background of the data.

Output should be 
[image]

```
Sample code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using log4net;
using System.Data;
namespace ReadAppendExcel
{
    public static class DataTable_Extensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Export DataTable to Excel file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="DataTable">Source DataTable</param>
        /// <param name="ExcelFilePath">Path to result file name</param>
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        public static void ExportToExcel(this System.Data.DataTable DataTable, string ExcelFilePath = null)
        {
            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
            ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
            try
            {
                int ColumnsCount;
                log.Info("In the ExportToExcel function");
                if (DataTable == null || (ColumnsCount = DataTable.Columns.Count) == 0)
                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

                // load excel, and create a new workbook
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbooks.Add();

                // single worksheet
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;
                int RowsCount = DataTable.Rows.Count;
                object[] Header = new object[ColumnsCount];
                object[] RowsCol = new object[RowsCount];
                // column headings               
                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                    Header[i] = DataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range HeaderRange = Worksheet.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, 1]), (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, ColumnsCount]));
                HeaderRange.Value = Header;
                HeaderRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
                HeaderRange.Font.Bold = true;

                // DataCells

                object[,] Cells = new object[RowsCount, ColumnsCount];
                Excel.Range range = Worksheet.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[2, 1]), (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowsCount + 1, ColumnsCount]));
                range.Value = RowsCol;
                for (int j = 0; j < RowsCount; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++) 
                        Cells[j, i] = DataTable.Rows[j][i];
                    if (DataTable.Rows[j][1].ToString() == "Failed")  // CHECKING CONDITION WITH THE DATATABLE
                    {
                        // USE TO COLOR THE ROW AND THE COLUMN RANGE 
                        range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

                    }
                    else if (DataTable.Rows[j][1].ToString() == "Running")
                    {
                        // USE TO COLOR THE ROW AND THE COLUMN RANGE 
                        range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                    }
                    else if (DataTable.Rows[j][1].ToString() == "Interrupted")
                    {
                        // USE TO COLOR THE ROW AND THE COLUMN RANGE 
                        range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                    }
                    else if (DataTable.Rows[j][1].ToString() == "Succeeded")
                    {
                        range.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                    }
                }
                Worksheet.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[2, 1]), (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowsCount + 1, ColumnsCount])).Value = Cells;
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                // check fielpath
                if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Worksheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
                        Excel.Quit();
                        log.Info("excel successfully created");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Info("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n" + ex.Message.ToString());
                        throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                            + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else    // no filepath is given
                {
                    Excel.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message.ToString());
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? The cells are not colored? Try adding Value like this: `DataTable.Rows[j][1].Value.ToString()`

Comment: Yea since it is overriding as with the last condition as the last condition is Succeed so it would be white.

Comment: All the ifs are not the same as the last one, Put this at the last if: `range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);`

Comment: When I put the line you mentioned there is no colour except white but in the dataTable there is "Failed" and "running" condition and even I had debugged and checked that it is entered inside the if and else if block. Since "succeed" is the last condition so it is taking the last colour.

Comment: I could able to color but there is one issue I'm facing with this code is that it is coloring one row less than the desired.

Comment: I have typed the code below. I need to know how to change the code as to match the exact rows i.e. total number of failure or running or succeed or interrupted

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using log4net;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ReadAppendExcel
{
    public static class DataTable_Extensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Export DataTable to Excel file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="DataTable">Source DataTable</param>
        /// <param name="ExcelFilePath">Path to result file name</param>
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        public static void ExportToExcel(this System.Data.DataTable DataTable, string ExcelFilePath = null)
        {
            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
            ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
            try
            {
                int ColumnsCount;
                log.Info("In the ExportToExcel function");
                if (DataTable == null || (ColumnsCount = DataTable.Columns.Count) == 0)
                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

                // load excel, and create a new workbook
                Excel.Application Excel = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbooks.Add();
                // single worksheet
                Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;
                int RowsCount = DataTable.Rows.Count;
                object[] Header = new object[ColumnsCount];
                object[] RowsCol = new object[RowsCount];
                // column headings               
                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                    Header[i] = DataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                // DataCells
                Excel.Range range;
                object[,] Cells = new object[RowsCount, ColumnsCount];
                //Excel.Range range = Worksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowsCount, ColumnsCount]), (Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowsCount + 1, ColumnsCount]));
                //range.Value = RowsCol;
                for (int j = 0; j <= RowsCount-1; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                    {
                        Cells[j, i] = DataTable.Rows[j][i];
                        if (DataTable.Rows[j][1].ToString() == "Failed")  // CHECKING CONDITION WITH THE DATATABLE
                        {
                              range = Worksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[j+1, i + 1]), (Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[j+1, i + 1]));
                              range.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
                        }
                        else if (DataTable.Rows[j][1].ToString() == "Running")
                        {
                            range = Worksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1]), (Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1]));
                            range.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
                        }
                        else if (DataTable.Rows[j][1].ToString() == "Interrupted")
                        {
                            range = Worksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1]), (Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1]));
                            range.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
                        }
                        else if (DataTable.Rows[j][1].ToString() == "Succeeded")
                        {
                            range = Worksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1]), (Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1]));
                            range.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.White);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Excel.Range HeaderRange = Worksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, 1]), (Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, ColumnsCount]));
                HeaderRange.Value = Header;
                HeaderRange.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Orange);
                HeaderRange.Font.Bold = true;
                range = Worksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[2, 1]), (Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowsCount, ColumnsCount]));
                Worksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[2, 1]), (Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowsCount, ColumnsCount])).Value = Cells;
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].Color = Color.Black.ToArgb();
                range.Columns.AutoFit();
                // check fielpath
                if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Worksheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);                        
                        Excel.Quit();
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Worksheet);
                        GC.Collect();
                        Process[] excelProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
                        foreach (Process p in excelProcesses)
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle)) // use MainWindowTitle to distinguish this excel process with other excel processes 
                            {
                                p.Kill();
                            }
                        }
                        DataTable.Dispose();
                        log.Info("excel successfully created");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Info("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n" + ex.Message.ToString());
                        throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                            + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else    // no filepath is given
                {
                    Excel.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message.ToString());
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```